# Child style.css not overwriting parent style.css

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I realise this has been asked before, but none of the previous questions help.

This is my function

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'flex-mag-style'; // This is 'flex-mag-style' for the Flex Mag theme.

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'flex-mag-child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Both stylesheets load, but none of the rules of the child styles.css show up when I inspect.

Comment: Perhaps the parent css selectors are more specific?

Comment: @Reality-Torrent I have made them pretty specific. Regardless, my styles don't even show when I inspect, but the stylesheet is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding below code. It worked for me.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

} ?>
```

Hope you have properly mentioned the parent theme name in the child theme style sheet as 
Template: (name of parent theme)

Comment: Yes, the Template: is the same as the parent theme directory name

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the comment block of the child style.css

It was nothing to do with the function